# Getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I´m working in a Java app and I keep getting the error in the title and I do not know why.

Here ir my code:

```
public static Object[] DataProcessinglcld(String in, String par){
    Object[] ret = new Object[2];
    if (in.contains("string" + par)){
        ret[0] = par;
        ret[1] = 0;
        return ret;
    }
    else{
        ret[0] = in;
        ret[1] = 1;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

...

```
    Object[] xlib = DataProcessinglcld(in[bit], "xlib.v");  // error line
    //System.arraycopy(DataProcessinglcld(in[bit], "xlib.v"), 0, xlib, 0, 2);
    bit++;
    ret[4] = xlib[0];
    ret[5] = xlib[1];
    if ( (int) xlib[1] == 1) {

        return FillWithZ(6,ret);
    }
```

I understand that the mentioned error is related to trying to acces wrong indices of an array, but as far as I understand I´m trying to assign an array of length 2 to another one to the same size.
Note that I get the same error if I just copy the result from DataProcessinglcld(in[bit], "xlib.v") to an array using the function in the comment below the problem line.

Comment: What's `bit` in `in[bit]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to access the position 4 and 5, unless that you have declared 'ret[x]' as a global array then you won't be able to access it, because it is declared inside a method.

```
ret[4] = xlib[0];
ret[5] = xlib[1];
```

Anyway you declare it with 2 objects:

```
Object[] ret = new Object[2];
```